# connection error while trying to plt.show()

Tags: matplotlib, urllib

I am using a remote interpreter in PyCharm to run code that plots heat maps. yesterday it worked fine, but today it stopped working without me changing the code or my conda environment.

I am trying to run this code:

```
...
...
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.imshow(img.permute(1,2,0))
ax2.imshow(heatmap)
plt.title(f'event: {event}')
plt.show()
```

but and it crushes on plt.show()

the exception I get is this:

```
...
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<user>/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display/datalore/display/display_.py", line 60, in try_empty_proxy
    urllib_request.urlopen(url, buffer)
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1383, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/home/<user>/miniconda3/envs/catenv/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer>
```

I searched for this error, and all questions regarding it were with people implementing request stuff, but i'm not implementing any internet related code.

btw: this exact bug happened to me in the past, and disappeared out of nowhere about two weeks later.

Comment: the full exception is the following:

Comment: What happens if you use the remote interpreter to perform some trivial task (e.g., `print(1)`) ? Is it possible that the peer on the other side of the wire doesn't want to talk to you, for whatever reason?